# inconsistent segmentation faults during runtime

Tags: c++

I'm currently taking a jab at [Project Euler #9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) and am encountering segmentation faults. These segfaults only occur with every 3rd-4th time I run the program. Could someone explain why this might be the case and more importantly, why it doesn't segfault (or work) every time instead?

I've pinpointed the segfault to the beginning of the 2nd `while` loop but still can't determine the root cause.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int square, sum, answer = -1;
    int start = 1;

    LinkedList tripletChoices;    

    while (square<=1000){
        //create new node
        node * factor = new node;
        factor->root = start;
        square = start*start;
        factor->square = square;

        //insert into list
        if (square<=1000) tripletChoices.insertNode(factor);

        start++;
    }

    node * a_factor = tripletChoices.head;

    /** segfaults just after this ***********************/
    cout<<"before segfault" << endl;

    while(a_factor->next!=NULL){

        cout<<"after segfault" << endl;

        node * b_factor = a_factor->next;

        while(b_factor->next!=NULL){
            sum = a_factor->square + b_factor->square;

            cout<<"A: " << a_factor->square << " B: " << b_factor->square<< " sum:" << sum <<endl;

            node * c_factor = tripletChoices.head;

            while(c_factor->next!=NULL){

                if (sum == c_factor->square){
                    if ((a_factor->root + b_factor->root + c_factor->root)==1000){
                        answer = a_factor->root * b_factor->root * c_factor->root;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                c_factor = c_factor->next;
            }

            b_factor = b_factor->next;
        }

        a_factor = a_factor->next;
    }

    cout<<"Answer: " << answer << endl;
}
```

the rest of my code (if relevant):

## LinkedList.h

```
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

struct node{
    int root;
    int square;
    node *next;
};

class LinkedList{
    public: 
        node * head;
        int listLength;

        //default constructor creates head node
        LinkedList();

        //setter method
        bool insertNode(node * newNode);

        //destructor de-allocates memory used by the list
        ~LinkedList();
};

#endif
```

## LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

//Default Constructor - initilizes list with head node
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
    listLength = 0;
}

// setter method for inserting a new node
// inserts new node at the head of the list
bool LinkedList::insertNode(node * newNode){
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    listLength++;
    return true;
}

//Destructor de-allocates memory used by list
LinkedList::~LinkedList(){
    node * p = head;
    node * q = head;

    while(q){
        p = q;
        q = p->next;
        if (q) delete p;
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined behavior

Comment: The segmentation fault is a consequence of the [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) exposed by your code. And because it is undefined, well, it doesn't follow any rule.

Comment: i'm an idiot. thanks

Comment: `if (q) delete p;` this seems wrong.

Comment: Instead of creating your own linked list class, why didn't you just use `std::list<node>`, where `node` is just `struct node {int root, square; };`?  The goal of the assignment is to solve the question, not get bogged down in creating home-made linked lists, right?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm quite new to C++. My understanding of LinkedLists is that each node always has a pointed to the next one. Is that not always the case?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my short term goal is to solve the question but my long term goal is to gain a better understanding of c/c++ and I figured the best way to do that is to start from the basics and do things yourself

Comment: @Geebs -- That's exactly right, so why write your own when one (actually two) already exist, [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) and [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).  You basically wasted a lot of time fighting with something that needed no fighting.

Comment: @Geebs `I figured the best way to do that is to start from the basics and do things yourself` -- To "do things yourself" to a beginner means to use the standard containers, libraries, etc.  If you want to write your own linked list **properly**, that takes far more experience than what the typical beginner can muster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for your insight - I'll be sure keep that in mind as I continue learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Undefined behavior because of accessing uninitialized local variable*

You are accessing *uninitialized variable* `square` before entering `while` loop, so it may or may not enter the `while` loop. So `tripletChoices.head` may or may not be non-null as you can't be sure if there would have happened any insertion or not!

Thus, dereferencing the `null` valued `a_factor` in `while(a_factor->next!=NULL)` would cause the SegFault.